# How to get the name of a proxy class?

Tags: java, logging, concurrency, proxy

I'm using the `java.util.concurrency` framework for the first time.  Here's a very simplified version of what I'm doing.  For those not intimately familiar with the framework, `future.get()` executes a `Callable` object defined in the future. `future.getOriginatingRequest()` returns an object I set in the future for use by the `Callable` object and I'm just trying to log which originating request object failed (its enough to know the class name of it).

```
try {
  future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  logger.error("Failed to execute future with id '" +
            future.getOriginatingRequest().getClass().getName() + "'");
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the logging framework is outputting this:

```
Failed to execute future with id '$Proxy22'
```

Thus instead of the real class name I am getting `$Proxy22` or some other number.  Is there a way to get ahold of the real class name rather than the proxy name?  Bonus points is someone can clearly explain why I'm getting the proxy string in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can answer the bonus question: the string is the name of a dynamic [`Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class, generated in runtime.

As for how you can get to the masked class, there's not even a guarantee that one exists at all. The only thing you can do is to call [`Proxy.getInvocationHandler()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getInvocationHandler%28java.lang.Object%29) on your proxy object and hope that the invocation handler will reveal more information (unlikely but may be worth a shot).

Comment: Thanks.  Any idea why a proxy class is getting involved at all? What are they for? After all I set the originating request object on the future (which I created myself) and am merely trying to get it back.

Comment: @Chris Knight are you using RMI or something similar?

Comment: @Chris Knight There could be several reasons for using proxies, but it usually involves either an action that has to be performed before and/or after every method call (an access check for example) or to be able to manipulate (or replace) the underlying object without anyone noticing it. But dynamic proxies are extremely powerful and versatile so it could be something entirely different.

Comment: Thanks.  We aren't using RMI but are using AspectJ which sounds like it meets that description in addition to some homegrown DI frameworks which could also be the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I find good for me solution on http://www.techper.net/2009/06/05/how-to-acess-target-object-behind-a-spring-proxy/

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
protected <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy, Class<T> targetClass) throws Exception {
  if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
    return (T) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
  } else {
    return (T) proxy; // expected to be cglib proxy then, which is simply a specialized class
  }
}
```

Usage

```
@Override
protected void onSetUp() throws Exception {
  getTargetObject(fooBean, FooBeanImpl.class).setBarRepository(new MyStubBarRepository());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i'm guessing that the proxy class is a subclass of the class you're looking for. especially if the class you're looking for is a class you wrote.

can you access the inheritance tree for the object you found? maybe through reflection?

Comment: Amongs other things, dynamic proxies are used to prevent this kind of tampering.

Comment: hmm, maybe not.. not so sure anymore. anyways, here's to guessing on stackoverflow D:

Comment: Good idea (I think), but doesn't work for me:  Here's my output: Class: $Proxy22
Super Class: java.lang.reflect.Proxy
Super Super Class: java.lang.Object